# Java 8 lambda aggregate

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda

I'm having a small problem with lambdas.  How can I iterate through it and add value every iteration to my variable *currentLateAmountDouble*?

```
BigDecimal currentLateAmountDouble = BigDecimal.ZERO;
Collection<VPO> lines = BO_Contract.getLines(trxName, contractVPO.getID(), RContractLine.LineNo + " ASC ", ctx);
if (lines != null && !lines.isEmpty()) {
    if (lines.stream()
             .filter(line -> onDate.compareTo(line.getDateValue(RContractLine.TermDate)) > 0) != null) {
        lines.forEach(line -> currentLateAmountDouble = currentLateAmountDouble.add(NumberUtils.getAmount(line.getDoubleValue(RContractLine.TotalAmountOpen))));
    }
}
```

It gives me an error on the 5th line:

> Local variable currentLateAmountDouble defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

The same method in Java 7 (works):

```
BigDecimal currentLateAmountDouble = BigDecimal.ZERO;
Collection<VPO> lines = BO_Contract.getLines(trxName, contractVPO.getID(), RContractLine.LineNo + " ASC ", ctx);
if (lines != null && !lines.isEmpty()) {
    for (VPO line : lines) {
        if (onDate.compareTo(line.getDateValue(RContractLine.TermDate)) > 0) {
            currentLateAmountDouble = currentLateAmountDouble.add(NumberUtils.getAmount(line.getDoubleValue(RContractLine.TotalAmountOpen)));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Solved!** Went with @JBNizet solution and did it like this:

```
currentLateAmountDouble = lines.stream().filter(line -> onDate.compareTo(line.getDateValue(RContractLine.TermDate)) > 0)
                .map(line -> NumberUtils.getAmount(line.getDoubleValue(RContractLine.TotalAmountOpen))).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, you may not reassign an external local variable from a lambda (just as from an anonymous class, in Java 7).

Trying to modify an external state from functional operations is a code smell. But your operation is just a mapping, followed by a reduction operation: you're transformaing each element to a BigDecimal, and then sum all the BigDecimals:

```
BigDecimal currentLateAmountDouble = 
   lines.stream()
        .map(line -> NumberUtils.getAmount(line.getDoubleValue(RContractLine.TotalAmountOpen)))
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Note that your test that compares the result of `filter()` with null doesn't make sense: `filter()` will never, ever return null. You're probably looking for `anyMatch` here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a reducing function...

try this in your if statement...

```
currentLateAmountDouble  = lines.stream().mapToInt(l->NumberUtils.getAmount(l.getDoubleValue( RContractLine.TotalAmountOpen)).sum();
```

it may not be exact, i'm not by a computer to test this out, but should get you close enough.

also, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html for reference